# Join Lookup from 1 table to multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I link 1 table with multiple columns in another table without using mutiple JOIN query?
Below is my scenario:

I have table `User` with `ID` and `Name`

```
User
+---------+------------+
|      Id |       Name |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |       John |
|       2 |       Mike |
|       3 |    Charles |
+---------+------------+
```

And table `Product` with multiple columns, but just focus on 2 columns `CreateBy` And `ModifiedBy`

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+
| product_id | CreateBy  | ModifiedBy  |
+------------+-----------+-------------+
|       1    | 1         | 3           |
|       2    | 1         | 3           |
|       3    | 2         | 3           |
|       4    | 2         | 1           |
|       5    | 2         | 3           |
+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

With normal `JOIN`, i will need to do 2 JOIN:

```
SELECT p.Product_id,
    u1.Name AS CreateByName,
    u2.Name AS ModifiedByName
FROM Product p
JOIN USER user u1 ON p.CreateBy = u1.Id,
JOIN USER user u2 ON p.ModifiedBy = u2.Id
```

to come out result

```
+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| product_id | CreateByName  | ModifiedByName  |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+
|       1    | John          | Charles         |
|       2    | John          | Charles         |
|       3    | Mike          | Charles         |
|       4    | Mike          | John            |
|       5    | Mike          | Charles         |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

How do i avoid that 2 times `JOIN`?

I'm using MS-SQL , but open to all SQL query for my own learning curious

Comment: You basically _can't_ avoid joining twice, because matching each column in the `Product` table requires one join.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen even if the answer is no, doesn't mean my question is not a valid, so why i have a downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote.  I have reversed it for you.

Comment: thanks @TimBiegeleisen, even though i'm using that multiple JOIN approach, still hope that someone could enlighten me with something i may not know

Comment: I mean, if you really needed to, you could restructure it by unpivoting then joining then re-pivoting that, but that's probably far more effort than simply two joins. Joins aren't evil. I don't know why you'd be averse to using them in a structure like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current design/approach is acceptable, I think, and the need for two joins is a function of there being two user ID columns.  Each of the two columns requires a separate join.

For fun, here is a table design which you may consider if you really want to have to perform only one join:

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+
| product_id | user_id   | type        |
+------------+-----------+-------------+
|       1    | 1         | created     |
|       2    | 1         | created     |
|       3    | 2         | created     |
|       4    | 2         | created     |
|       5    | 2         | created     |
|       1    | 3         | modified    |
|       2    | 3         | modified    |
|       3    | 3         | modified    |
|       4    | 1         | modified    |
|       5    | 3         | modified    |
+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Now, you can get away with a just a single join followed by an aggregation:

```
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'created'  THEN u.Name END) AS CreateByName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'modified' THEN u.Name END) AS ModifiedByName
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN user u
    ON p.user_id = u.Id
GROUP BY
    p.product_id;
```

Note that I *don't* recommend this approach at all.  It is much cleaner to use your current approach and use two joins.  Joins can fairly easily be optimized using one or more indices.  The above aggregation approach would probably not perform as well as what you already have.

Comment: yes i agree that, by changing table structure from the begin will help to resolve this, but it's against the main purpose of existing tables, when returning "User Name" is just a simpler purpose such as a report.

Answer (score 1):

If you use natural keys instead of surrogates, you won't need to join at all.
I don't know how you tell your products apart in the real world, but for the example I will assume you have a UPC

```
CREATE TABLE User 
(Name VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE Product 
(UPC CHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY, 
CreatedBy VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES User(Name),
ModifiedBy VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES User(Name)
);
```

Now your query is a simple select, and you also enforce uniqueness of your user names as a bonus, and don't need additional indexes.
Try it...

HTH

Comment: thanks , i understand your idea of using references Name instead of ID, but it will against table purpose when changing existing db structure, plus it will affects other table, too

Comment: It will only affect it for the better... what are your concerns?

Comment: the concern is you will need to change existing logic to that to whichever piece of code that using this Product table. Not to mention about migrating for existing data

Answer (score 1):

Join is the best Approach, but if looking for alternate approach you can use Inline Query.

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID,
       (SELECT [NAME] FROM @USER WHERE ID = CREATED_BY) AS CREATED_BY,
       (SELECT [NAME] FROM @USER WHERE ID = MODIFIED_BY) AS MODIFIED_BY
FROM @PRODUCT P
```

[DEMO](https://rextester.com/NGA38136)

Comment: The user table's `ID` column stores numbers, not "CREATED_BY" or "MODIFIED_BY".

Comment: Yes it's number only, created_by and modified_by are product table columns. Please check Demo link provided.

Comment: agree with this, it's another approach but you still need to do 2 times `Select` from same `[User]` table, so I rather using Join to reduce the complicated